# Pyspark: AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: python, hive, pyspark

Im trying to find a specific string in a file and then replace it with another specific string. I'm using a Zeppelin notebook. 
Here is my code thus far..

```
%pyspark
import fileinput
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
hivectx = HiveContext(sc)
file = sc.textFile('PATH/my_query.sql')
file1 = sc.textFile('PATH/my_query1sql')
phrase = "(Month|| '-' || '5' || '-' || year)"
replace ="('5' || '/' || month || '/' || year)"

read = file.collect()


//for i in read:
     //print i     ---> this successfully prints out my_query.sql file  


for i in read:
    file1 = file1.map(lambda x: x.replace(phrase, replace))
    file1.saveAsTextFile(file1)   // im trying to save it as the empty file "PATH/my_query.sql" also known as file1.
```

However, i'm receiving this error:

```
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

I cannot find any documentation online about this error with '_get_object_id'. Similar errors state that its a version issue?

Is this the case? Is there a blatant error in my code? Sorry im a noob to the language :p

Comment: Can you try your map function on the read object instead of your Spark RDD? It is also interesting you would use Spark for this kind of work.

Comment: @BernardL, Thanks for the time! Im using zeppelin which is on my hadoop sandbox. Only way to use leverage python :) Could you provide an example? Do you mean like this?
(`read = file.map(lambda x: x.replace(phrase, replace))
for i in read:
    file1.saveAsTextFile(file1)`)

Comment: No need to call `collect` here (defeats the purpose of spark). Remove everything after the line `replace ="('5' || '/' || month || '/' || year)"`. Then add **only** the following (in place of what was removed): `file1.map(lambda x: x.replace(phrase, replace)).saveAsTextFile("PATH/my_query.sql")`. No need for an explicit loop either - spark takes care of that for you.

Comment: That's awesome that spark does that for you! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @SarahBratz spark is meant for large data processing. If your data can fit in memory of your local computer, then you should not be using spark.

Comment: @pault Spark is gaining lots of traction as a standalone node rather than only for clusters. I think it is important that people understand the core usages of it but it definitely has its own benefits such as larger than memory processing.

Comment: Thanks for the insight :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace a certain text pattern in your file, you can try the following without the use of Spark, it probably is gonna be more efficient for a small file like a SQL query.

```
with open('PATH/file.sql','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

phrase = "(Month|| '-' || '5' || '-' || year)"
replace ="('5' || '/' || month || '/' || year)"

new_lines = ''.join([i.replace(phrase,replace) for i in lines])

print(new_lines)

with open('text.sql', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_lines)
```

The file is read and stored into a list here, the replace function will then be applied to all of the lines of the file and joins it. Finally, write the file you want to save it as.

Comment: Thanks for you input! I appreciate all the help! That definitely looks more efficient for smaller files.

Comment: If it helps, please accept this as an answer (below the tick boxes). Other than choosing the right tool, you would want to focus on code readability as well. Hope it helps!

Comment: The prior comment was the solution for my spark case. However this would be a perfectly appropriate answer for the scenario without spark